# Authentication failure

Tags: php, email

I am using windows server, When i send the mail using smtp and pear function the response error showing

> authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 535, response: Authentication failed)]

like this, But username, password and host are correct.

Comment: please help me...

Comment: Are you using Gmail to send an email via SMTP?

Comment: Please add more details, e.g. what smtp server are you using? If it is gmail please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031009/pear-mail-authentication-failure-when-sending-emails)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PEAR mail authentication failure when sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20031009/pear-mail-authentication-failure-when-sending-emails)

Comment: try SMTP 578 please and please share brief info here